# How can I catch a symbol that user is hit on keyboard?

Tags: silverlight

Yes, many controls have KeyUp/KeyDown propertys. But in they arguument I can catch Key class only. Not real symbol.
For example, when user type "d" symbol is become a Key.D in KeyDown. All symbols in any other langauge that stay on the same plase on keyboard will be Key.D too.

How I can get analog of KeyPress in WPF that can represent a char (symbol) to catch a native typing depended on local langauge?

Answer (score 1):

read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#text_inputReal
It seems that what you need to do is to handle the `TextInput` event rather than the `KeyUp/KeyDown` events.
This is probably the same difference as handling `WM_CHAR` rather than `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP`

Comment: There is no WM_CHAR or KeyPress event or anything like that in the current Silverlight.

Comment: luckly was talking about WPF.